# C# How do i make a timer Check if a ComboBox has more items?

Tags: c#, timer, combobox

Ok so this is what i got right now:

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send(comboBox3.Text);
    ComboBox3.SelectedIndex += 1;
    SendKeys.Send(comboBox4.Text);
    ComboBox4.SelectedIndex += 1;
}
```

but i want it so if there is more than one item in ComboBox3 that it changes and types that 1st before it does ComboBox4 and if there isnt more than one i want it to jus continue to ComboBox4

also this is my 1st post on this website so srry if you dnt understand

Comment: Why don't you just use `ComboBox1.Items.Count` so see how many items the combobox has?

Comment: Ok, what i understand is that you want to check if a ComboBox contains more than 1 item, but `i want it to use the 1st combobox always before it uses the 2nd one` you want what to use the first ComboBox before the second? the OpenFileDialog?

Comment: Your question is unclear. More items than what? What is `Combobox1.Selectedindex(+1)` supposed to do? Are you trying to process each item in a combo box, one at each timer tick? This seems like a really odd thing to be doing. Can you give us a little more background, like what are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: `SelectedIndex` is a property, not a method. To increment it you'd do: `Combobox1.SelectedIndex += 1;` or just: `Combobox1.SelectedIndex ++;`.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, I'm pretty sure a timer won't be involved.  You might have to explain better why you are trying to track these changes in the ComboBoxes, give us an example.

Comment: `SelectedIndex = +1` makes the selected item in the combobox go further by one

Comment: I ment `SelectedIndex += 1` makes the selected item go further by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for an `if` statement?

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ComboBox3.Items.Count > 1)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(comboBox3.Text);
    }
    //rest of code
}
```